# Angular 5+ Sibling Component Communication Using RxJS (Subject)

Tags: angular, rxjs

My app has listing of tiles that when clicked on will display in a dashboard.  In the dashboard, when a tile is clicked, the tile details show below the dashboard (not unlike tour-of-heroes).

I’m using RxJS Subject in a service to communicate successfully between Component A (available snippets), Component B (the dashboard), and the Component C (snippet details).

The problem is that when I click on the one of the listings on component A, not only does it populate the dashboard like it should but also populates the details (Component C). I only want the details to be populated when the tile is clicked on in the dashboard - yes, the details do successfully populate when a dashboard tile is clicked.

All 3 components are siblings residing in app.component.html.
I do not want parent-child relationships - hence using `Subject` instead of `@Inupt`.

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SnippetService {

  tile  = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }

  getSnippets(): Observable<Snippet[]> {
    return of (SNIPPETS);
  }

  addTile(data) {
    this.tile.next(data);
  }

}
```

Component A (available tiles/snippets):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-available-snippets',
  templateUrl: './available-snippets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./available-snippets.component.css']
})
export class AvailableSnippetsComponent implements OnInit {

  snippets: Snippet[];

  constructor(private snippetService: SnippetService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSnippets();
  }

  getSnippets(): void {
    this.snippetService.getSnippets().subscribe(x => this.snippets = x);
  }

  onAddTile(data) {
    this.snippetService.addTile(data);
  }

}
```

Component B (The dashboard):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedSnippet: Snippet;

  addedSnippets = [];

  // Inject the SnippetService
  constructor(private snippetService: SnippetService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.snippetService.tile.subscribe(x => this.addToDashboard(x));
  }

  addToDashboard(s: Snippet) {
    if (this.addedSnippets.indexOf(s) === -1) {
      this.addedSnippets.push(s);
    }
  }

  displayDetails(s: Snippet) {
    this.snippetService.addTile(s);
  }

}
```

Component C (snippet details)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-snippet-detail',
  templateUrl: './snippet-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snippet-detail.component.css']
})
export class SnippetDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  snippet: Snippet;

  constructor(private snippetService: SnippetService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.snippetService.tile.subscribe(x => this.snippet = x);
  }

}
```

Component C Template:

```
<div class="snippet-detail" *ngIf="snippet">
  <hr>
  <h2>{{ snippet.title }} </h2>
  <div>{{snippet.description}}</div>
  <code>{{snippet.code.example1}}</code>
  <code>{{snippet.code.example2}}</code>
  <code>{{snippet.code.example3}}</code>
</div>
```

So the the culprit is between the `ngOnInit{}` in Component C and the `*ngIf="snippet`" on C's view.  I tried passing additional booleans from the service but the problem is that I need the state of those bools to be in a lifecycle loop.

So a RxJS'y way of doing this?

Comment: You need to have multiple subjects in your service then. One for the tile to show on the dashboard and another for the one to show in the detail view.

Comment: Additionally, you could not have a parent-child relationship and still use `@Input()`s. Use `@Output()`s to broadcast the data to your parent component which gives the data via an `@Input()`.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Thank you.  Posted answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SnippetService {

  tile  = new Subject<any>();
  details  = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }

  getSnippets(): Observable<Snippet[]> {
    return of (SNIPPETS);
  }

  addTile(data) {
    this.tile.next(data);
  }

  showDetails(data) {
    this.details.next(data);
  }

}
```

Component B (Dashboard) now passes the snippet to the snippet.service `showDetails()` method:

```
  displayDetails(s: Snippet) {
    this.snippetService.showDetails(s);
  }
```

Component C (details) now subscribes to the details subject and assigns the result to C's snippet property:

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.snippetService.details.subscribe(x => this.snippet = x);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in certain situations when sending an
`Observable <primitive>`
`ie: Observable<boolean>()`
that you need to wrap the boolean in an object like this.

```
//In a component somewhere.

// decleration of observable 
scrollTopNotify$: Observable<BooleanValue> = of<BooleanValue>({value: false});

//  setting a value later.  Because it is now an object the reference changes and
//  it triggers the change more reliably for subscribers and async pipe subscribers.
this.scrollTopNotify$ = of<BooleanValue>({value: true});

// ie: in template: [scrollTopNotify]="(scrollTopNotify$ | async)">

//boolean-value.ts file
export interface BooleanValue {
    value: boolean;
}
```