# Angular and RxJS: Updating the Subject?

Tags: angular, rxjs

This is along the lines of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889376/angular-5-sibling-component-communication-using-rxjs-subject) but now I have a new issue.

My app shows a dashboard of tiles.  I'm using Subjects for component communication.  When a tile is removed from the dashboard, I need the the data from the `tile-details.component`'s view to disappear.  As it is, the data remains in the details view after the tile is removed.

I wanted to accomplish this by manipulating the data stream (the details subject), since that is what `tile-details.component` is reacting to.

Here's the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class TileService {

  tile  = new Subject<any>();
  details  = new Subject<any>();

  tiles = [];

  constructor() { }

  getTiles(): Observable<Tile[]> {
    return of (TILES);
  }

  addTile(data) {
    this.tile.next(data);
  }

  addDetail(data) {
   this.details.next(data);
  }
}
```

dashboard.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Dashboard';

  // Tiles to show on dashboard
  tiles = [];

  editing = false;

  constructor(private tileService: TileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // We only want tiles that have been clicked on in available-tiles.component to show in the dashboarrd.
    // The available-tiles.component adds to the tiles subject when a tile is clicked.
    // Populate the tiles array based on the data stream from the tile subject.
    this.tileService.tile.subscribe(x => this.populateTilesArr(x));
  }

  populateTilesArr(t: Tile) {
    if (this.tiles.indexOf(t) === -1) {
      this.tiles.push(t);
    }
  }

  remove(t) {
     // remove tile from array
    const index = this.tiles.indexOf(t);
    this.tiles.splice(index, 1);

   // *** Do something with details subject here? ***

    if (this.tiles.length < 1) {
      this.editing = false;
    }

  }

  displayDetails(t: Tile) {
    this.tileService.addDetail(t);
  }

}
```

dashboard.component.html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  <p *ngIf="tiles.length >= 1; else instructions">Click a tile to view code snippets</p>
  <ng-template #instructions>
      Click a tile from the selection on the left to populate the dashboard.
  </ng-template>
<div *ngIf="tiles.length >= 1">
    <button (click)="editing = true" [disabled] = "editing">Edit Dashboard</button>
    <button *ngIf="editing" (click)="editing = false">Done</button>
</div> 
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor = "let tile of tiles" (click)="displayDetails(tile)">
        <button  *ngIf="editing" class="remove" (click)="remove(tile)">X</button>
        <span class="title">{{tile.title}}</span> 
        <span class="desc">{{tile.description}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

tile-detail.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tile-detail',
  templateUrl: './tile-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tile-detail.component.css']
})
export class TileDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  tile: Tile;

  constructor(private tileService: TileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tileService.details.subscribe(x => this.tile = x);
  }

}
```

tile-detail.component.html:

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="tile">
  <hr>
  <h2>{{ tile.title }} </h2>
  <p>{{tile.description}}</p>
    <code>{{tile.code.snippetA}}</code>
    <code>{{tile.code.snippetB}}</code>
    <code>{{tile.code.snippetC}}</code>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like you should be passing a `tile` input property from dashboard to tile-component.ts. It might help to see the templates as well.

Comment: You may want to look into using https://github.com/ngrx for managing your application state

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thank you. I'm already using RxJS - reacting to data streams, manipulating the stream and producing another reaction. In my view that should do it. Its upon a change to the data and updating the subject I think is the issue.

Comment: Did you try this? `this.tileService.addDetail(null);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have in your tile detail component, you should just need to `null` out your `tile` property. Tracing back through the tile service and dashboard, you can just push a new `null` value in your service from your dashboard like this in your `remove` method:

```
this.tileService.addDetail(null);
```

**Update**

Based on your comment below, you'll need to update your dashboard component to hold onto the selected tile shown in the detail view.

```
selectedTile: Tile;
```

Now when you select a tile you need to not only use your service, you need to set this new property to it:

```
displayDetails(t: Tile) {
    this.tileService.addDetail(t);
    this.selectedTile = t;
}
```

Additionally, you need to modify the remove code to this (in place of the original code above):

```
if (this.selectedTile === tile) {
    this.displayDetails(null);
}
```

Comment: A complication with your answer: Deleting the tile from the dashboard will also delete whatever detail is showing i.e.Tile A is removed from the dashboard while Tile B's detail was showing so B's detail gets removed.  It would be nice if it only  the detail was removed corresponding the the actual tile what was removed from the dashboard.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you'll need to hold onto the currently displayed tile in your dashboard. Then when you remove a tile, if it is the currently displayed tile you remove it as shown in the answer, otherwise do nothing with it.

Comment: Your updated answer solved the issue.  Thanks again.